# How do I display grouped results in an EmberJS Application

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've created a simple EmberJS application that lists jobs from a headless CMS. The jobs data from the backend is in this format

```
[
   {
      "id": "1234",
      "description": "Test description"
      "category": "Human Resources"
   },
   {
      "id": "4321",
      "description": "Test description"
      "category": "Human Resources"
   },
   {
      "id": "5678",
      "description": "Test description"
      "category": "Information Technology"
   }
]
```

My app displays the results in the order that they're returned as expected but I'd like to group the results by category so that the results are displayed like this:

Human Resources

- 1234
- 4321

Information Technology

- 5678

Thanks in advance for any help.

Note: I'm using EmberJS version 3.19

EDIT

My current model is just the job model

```
import Model, { attr } from "@ember-data/model";

export default class JobModel extends Model {
  @attr Title;
  @attr Description;
  @attr Type;
  @attr Slug;
  @attr category;
  @attr job_type;
  @attr region;
  @attr company;
  @attr createdAt;
}
```

I load the data using `ember-data` in my index route (home page) like this

```
export default class IndexRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  async model() {
    return this.store.findAll("job");
  }
}
```

With that setup, I can iterate through the jobs and display them in a list on my home page like this:

```
{{#each @model as |job|}}
        <Job @job={{job}} />
{{/each}}
```

Not sure if it is possible but I want to be able to display each category and the jobs included in that category with a structure like the below pseudocode:

```
{{#each category}}
<h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
  {{#each job-in-category}}
        <Job @job={{job}} />
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: How do you currently load and display the data? What models do you have? Could you show some code?

Comment: @Lux thanks for responding. I've edited the question a bit and added some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could either add the logic to your routes `model` hook or create a Controller and use a getter.

In the route you could do

```
  async model() {
    const jobs = await this.store.findAll("job");
    return jobs.reduce((groups, job) => {
      if(!groups.has(job.category)) {
        groups.set(job.category, []);
      }
      groups.get(job.category).push(job);
      return groups;
    }, new Map());
  }
```

and use it in your template:

```
{{#each-in @model as |category jobs|}}
  <h3>{{category}}</h3>
  {{#each jobs as |job|}}
    <Job @job={{job}} />
  {{/each}}
{{/each-in}}
```

you could produce the same structure in a getter on the controller or use a dedicated component for it. Also maybe you want to create a dedicated `ember-data` model for your category and use a relationship.

Comment: Are you sure that you can use a native `Map` in a template? I thought this causes issues and you need to use a `TrackedMap` instead. Or is this only an issue if the map is mutated after first render?

Comment: this is indeed only a issue if you a) mutate the map after the first render and b) dont update the relevant `@tracked`. In this case it is ok because the entire map will be recreated when something in the tracking context changes.